# Proof on representing the incomplete beta function as a hypergeometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-function, beta-function

The [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) is defined as

$$B(x;c,d) = \int_0^xt^{c-1}(1-t)^{d-1}dt.$$

The [hypergeometric representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.26.0005.01)  of the incomplete Beta function is given by
\begin{equation}
B\left(x; c,d \right)=\frac{x^c}{c}{}_2F_1\left( c,1-d;1+c;x \right)
\end{equation}

where \begin{equation}
B(b,c-b)\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \int_0^1 x^{b-1} (1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a} \, dx
\end{equation}

B(b,c-b) the [ beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Anyone know a nice elementary proof to this? Preferably one that doesn't expand the series out, and that someone with two semester of calculus would understand.  But if not, what is the standard way to prove this?

To be clear, these two integral are equal, how can I show it

Comment: It is known to.  The result can be found all over the internet, although without proof. It can be verified by expanding series out over a certain region.